# gradle Exec empty commandLine then add arguments

Tags: gradle, exec

gradle Exec:

```
task foo(type: Exec) {
    commandLine ''
    if (windows)
        args 'cmd', '/c'

    args "mysql -u root -pPassword < db.sql"
}
```

Error:

```
CommandLine==null!
```

is there a way to add args (command is an argument) conditionally?

Comment: have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use multiple `commandLine` ?

This can be easily achieved with that like the following:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
task ifWindows(type:Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX)) {
        commandLine("cmd", "/c", "echo", "Linux")
    }
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine("cmd", "/c", "echo", "WINDOS")
    }
}
```

And you can pass any command you want this way and it depends on Operating system.